# Repainting a JPanel with a different Image whenever you click on it

Tags: java, swing, repaint, mouselistener

I'm still very new to Java and I have the following problem.
As you can see below I've created a JPanel with an image that I want to change whenever I click on the panel, but It doesn't work for some reason. I've been sitting on it for hours now and seem to be completely stuck. If you could take a look at the code and help me I would be very grateful.
Thank you and have a nice Christmas.

```
public class Level {
  JPanel panel
  String img1Path = "img1.png";
  String img2Path = "img2.png";
  Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(img1Path);
  Image img2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(img2Path);
  boolean s1 = false;

  public Level(){
    initGUI();
  }

  public void initGUI(){
    panel = new JPanel(){
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);
       draw(g,s1);
      }
    }
   panel.addMouseListener(new ImgListener(s1));
  }

  public void draw(Graphics g, boolean s){
    if(s==true){
      g.drawImage(img1,0,0,this);}
    else if(s==false){
      g.drawImage(img2,0,0,this);}
    }//draw()

  public void click(boolean s, boolean b){
    s = b;
    repaint();
  }

  public class ImgListener extends MouseAdapter {
    boolean s;

    public ImgListener(boolean s){
      pS(s);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
      if(s==true){
        click(s,false);
      }
      else if(s==false){
        click(s,true);
      }
   }//mouseClicked

  public void pS(boolean s){
    this.s = s;
   }//pS

  }//ImgListener

}//Level
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java is pass-by-value *always*, and so your click method will not change your class's boolean field:

```
public void click(boolean s, boolean b){
  s = b;  // this does not change the class field s.
  repaint();
}
```

The reason is the `s` parameter above is not the same as the class's `s` field, but instead the parameter does what is known as "shadows" the class field. A solution is to change this method and get rid of the s parameter. Or better -- **get rid of the method entirely.**

Note that if this were my application, I'd use a JLabel, give it a MouseListener, and simply swap ImageIcons on mousePressed.

Also your boolean toggle method:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
  if(s==true){
    click(s,false); 
  }
  else if(s==false){
    click(s,true);
  }
}
```

can be greatly simplified *and corrected* by doing this and getting rid of the erroneous click(...) method:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
  s = !s;
  repaint();
}
```

As an aside, `if (s == true)` is unnecessarily redundant. If you need a construct like this, you can more succinctly and simply do `if (s)`. Same for `if (s == false)` which is better represented as `if (!s)`

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for answering. The reason I use a JPanel instead of a label is because I'm going to put multiple different images later on and I want each one of them to change whenever it is clicked (they are going to be arrows that change their direction on click). Is there any way to change the s parameter or maybe could you give me some other advice to do that?

Comment: @Bash: I would then populate the JPanel with JLabels whose icons are swapped when clicked on. What you need to know then is which JLabel was clicked on, and that is easy to figure out with the MouseEvent's `getSource()` method. Then check what icon is showing in the selected JLabel and swap it.

Comment: Is it possible to put those JLabels on top of another image which is supposed to be a background image?

Comment: @Bash: piece of cake. One way is to override the backing JPanel's paintComponent method and draw the background image there, but even easier would be to use a JLabel with ImageIcon as the main container instead of a JPanel. Just give it a decent layout manager.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I will try doing that. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Bash: good luck! Please come back and ask a new question if you get stuck on a step.